# Ember.js: OK to avoid this.get('attr')?

Tags: ember.js

My Ember.js model, view, and controller classes are getting a bit verbose. Part of this comes from writing `this.get('attr')` instead of `this.attr`.

Is it OK to always just write `this.attr`, as long as the attribute is declared directly, not via a binding?

(I understand that setting is a different issue -- you always have to call `this.set('attr', value)` in order to update dependent attributes and templates.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, you can do this for private properties that you know will not be observable.

The convention is to prefix your private properties with an underscore (eg _myProperty) which tells Ember not to bind it.

See the docs for [.get()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_get), or check the [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/36cd4b65dec8b564bed66613a966403e410f32a2/packages_es6/ember-metal/lib/property_get.js) if you're so inclined.

Comment: Link appears to be broken

Answer (score 3):

If the property is being observed or bound, you DON'T want to do 'this.attr'. The get command is the nexus through which observers and bindings are triggered.

Comment: Interesting. So under what circumstances would the get command trigger an observer or binding? I thought it just passively reads the current value. (I was expecting set, not get, to trigger observers and bindings.)

Comment: @JoLiss: I think that would be the case when you try to read a computed property that depends on other properties, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers to that question are outdated by recent version of Ember. Since 3.1, which was released in April 2018, native ES5 getters could be used for computed properties also. In Ember 3.1 `this.get('attr')` is the object uses `unknownProperty`, is an Ember Data `PromiseProxyObject` or if using with a path and some elements of it may not be an object. Please refer to [release notes](https://blog.emberjs.com/2018/04/13/ember-3-1-released.html) for details. You will get a helpful assertion in that cases.